# Length of Longest Common sequence Python recursive function

Tags: python, longest-substring

I am trying to implement this function with recursion in python and I have a mistake. I can't understand what is the mistake, could you help me?

The code:

```
def LongestCommonSubsequence(X,Y,tailX,tailY):
    if tailX == tailY and tailX!='' and (X=='' or Y==''):
            return len(tailX)
    elif X=='' or Y=='':
            return 0
    else:

        return max( LongestCommonSubsequence(X[1:],Y[1:],tailX+X[0],tailY+Y[0]),
                    LongestCommonSubsequence(X[1:],Y[1:],tailX+X[0],tailY),
                    LongestCommonSubsequence(X[1:],Y[1:],tailX,tailY+Y[0]),
                    LongestCommonSubsequence(X[1:],Y[1:],tailX,tailY)) 

X=raw_input() 
Y=raw_input() 
print LongestCommonSubsequence(X,Y,'','')
```

input:

```
abccdabab 
bacdbeb
```

expected output:5
what i get:4

Comment: Will X and Y always be strings? If they're some other collection, ex. a list, then `elif X=='' or Y==''` will always be False. You could take advantage of the inherent type conversion of boolean contexts and just do `elif not X or not Y:`

Comment: I duped this to a working LLCS implementation; it works for strings as well as lists.

Comment: If you want this reopened, please provide more information. Give us sample input, expected output, what you get instead (including error messages) and where you yourself think the problem lies. As it stands this isn't a good question.

Comment: input: abccdabab
bacdbeb
expected output:5
what i get:4

Comment: This is not a duplicated question, I have not found a recursive implementation !

Comment: Thanks for providing expected and actual output :-) But I'm not entirely familiar with this kind of problem. You seem to have provided arguments for X and Y, but what should we use for `tailX` and `tailY`? Can you show exactly how to call `LongestCommonSubsequence`?

Comment: yes : X=raw_input()
        Y=raw_input()
        print LongestCommonSubsequence(X,Y,'','')

Comment: when I call the function tailX and tailY are empty. I use them to store the subsequences.

Comment: Why are you storing subsequences in reverse order? Why store them *at all*?

Comment: First, this is not a reversed order. Second, I should have written "store" because this is not actually storing them..

Comment: You appear to be storing the **head**, not the tail of your strings under test, which is why it does make sense to append to the existing head-so-far each time. So you get `a` then `ab` then `abc`. But that doesn't actually explain why you are doing that.

Comment: How else would I go through all the options for sub strings recursively ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be trying to optimise for common tail strings here; if both strings end with the same tail you can indeed skip a few recursion steps.

But you are not actually building a tail, you are building the **head**, the characters at the start.

Here is a working recursive `llcs` without that optimisation:

```
def llcs(xstr, ystr):
    if not xstr or not ystr:
        return 0
    x, xtail, y, ytail = xstr[0], xstr[1:], ystr[0], ystr[1:]
    if x == y:
        return 1 + llcs(xtail, ytail)
    return max(llcs(xstr, ytail), llcs(xtail, ystr))
```

This finds the maximum longest common substring length by comparing lengths found for removing a character from the start of either `xstr` or `ystr`, **not both**.

Your code specifically never pairs up `X` with `Y[1:]` or `X[1:]` with `Y` for the `max()` call, so you never will find an LCS for that specific starting character in either `X` or `Y`.

You can then try and optimise by looking at `xtail` and `ytail` (actual tails) and bail out early:

```
def llcs(xstr, ystr):
    if not xstr or not ystr:
        return 0
    x, xtail, y, ytail = xstr[0], xstr[1:], ystr[0], ystr[1:]
    if x == y:
        if xtail == ytail:
            # if the tails match, bail out early
            return 1 + len(xtail)
        return 1 + llcs(xtail, ytail)
    return max(llcs(xstr, ytail), llcs(xtail, ystr))
```

Comment: I can't see how is this recursive.. and I don't want to find the longest one - I just wan't to find that length.

Comment: @michaelkova: it is recursive but I made typos in the recursive call name. The *length* is returned, not the actual substring. The functions return `5` for your sample input.

Comment: Oh OK I thought you used the lcs function. Well It does work ! Thank you. Can you explain me why your first implementation works ? I'm having trouble understanding that.

Comment: @michaelkova: take a grid, lay out one string along the top, the other along the side. Then mark all the cells where you have a matching character (that's the `x == y` case); the maximum length is then created as a path through the grid from top left to bottom right, where you can only go right or down. The recursion just looks at the top left cell and sees the rest of the table as a recursive call, one for a step to the right, and one for a step down, and it'll pick the one with the highest value returned.

Comment: @michaelkova: the step to the right and the step down are implemented as substrings; remove the first character of `x` is one direction, remove the first character of `y` is another.

Comment: @michaelkova: see the [wikipedia page on the problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem), where you'll see such tables and lengths filled in. Recursion is the *traceback approach*.